# How to SELECT from two different columns in condition Order by another table and join them by SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

Table1 is ..

```
     firstname  |   lastname  

     Peter      |    Das

     Das        |    James

     vector     |   Call

     cans       |    Das
```

and table2 is

```
 id |  user   |  roll
 ___________________
 1 |  cans   |  5

 2 |  James  |  2

 3 |  Peter  |  8

 4 | vector |  6
```

And I want the output result as

```
 id |   name
 __________
 3 |  Peter

 1 |  Cans

 2 |  James
```

And the description of the sql query may be like this

```
SELECT (lastname WHERE firstname='Das' AND firstname WHERE lastname='Das' FROM table1 AS name
(SELECT roll from table2 AS rollorder WHERE user=name) ORDER BY rollorder DESC
```

here the order nust should be table2

I don't know this sql query

so please help me

Every ideas and suggestions are welcome

Comment: You need to learn basics of querying.. Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a much simpler query when I first saw.. here you go this should work..

Answer (score 1):

```
   select t2.id, (case when t1.lastname = 'Das' then t1.firstname
                 when t1.firstname = 'Das' then t1.lastname end)
    from (select (case when lastname = 'Das' then firstname
                       when firstname = 'Das' then lastname end) as name_to_compare,
                 firstname,
                 lastname
            from table1
           where firstname = 'Das' or 
                 lastname = 'Das') t1 inner join
          table2 t2 on t1.name_to_compare = t2.users
    order by t2.roll desc
```

EDIT: some mistakes rectified, this should work perfectly. Tested on test data. User is a keyword, so replaced it with users. Replace with the appropriate column in your database.

Comment: sorry there was a slight error in the case statement - the column names were wrong. Correcting it..

Comment: I have edited it three hours back.. as soon as i gave the comment.

Comment: I have tried a lot but its not working to me .. may be i am a fool